# Why use token and secret key

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth

A developer created a website with a front-end and back-end communicating with API's and believe created custom authentication. The user completes a login form (username and password) and sends it to the server. These details are validated against the DB and then the previously stored Token and Secret(when registered user) is sent back to client.

When the user registers it uses this code and saves keys in DB:

> schemaObj.Token =
>   crypto.createHash('sha1').update(uuidv4()).update(conf.hidden.salt).digest('hex');
>   schemaObj.Secret
>   =crypto.createHash('sha256').update(uuidv4()).update(conf.hidden.secret).digest('hex');

I looked at several resources but cant figure out why a secret is needed. Would not a token by itself be sufficient in confirming the user ?
Is this a custom authentication solution ?